# Can't get key's value after subscribing for expiration

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a shallow key, which is supposed to expire, after listening to its expiration, I take the key, generate the key which holds the real value and try to get its value.

Code:

```
//.: Set the config for "notify-keyspace-events" channel used for expired type events
listener.send_command('config', ['set','notify-keyspace-events','Ex']);

// __keyevent@0__:expired is the channel name to which we need to subscribe, 0 is the default DB
listener.subscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired');
listener.on('message', (chan, msg) => {
  listener.get(`${msg}-details`, redis.print);
});
```

Getting the error below after running listener.get:

**ReplyError: ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this context**

**I need the real key's value.**

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [`SUBSCRIBE` command](https://redis.io/commands/subscribe):

> Once the client enters the subscribed state it is not supposed to
> issue any other commands, except for additional SUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE,
> UNSUBSCRIBE, PUNSUBSCRIBE, PING and QUIT commands.

The usual pattern is you would have two client connections (you would call `redis.createClient()` twice). Here is an example: [How to receive Redis expire events with node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027970/how-to-receive-redis-expire-events-with-node)

Basically, you would have one connection for the expiration events, and one for the other logic you want (getting the key value, etc).